# Is there a faster way to stream objects from S3 over Web Api to my Angular client instead of using their response stream?

Tags: c#, angular, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api2

To implement secure file downloads, my Angular client requests a one time token, then the browser hits this endpoint with the token to initiate the download from the Asp.Net Web Api.  The server then retrieves the object from amazon, I copy their response stream over to a MemoryStream like so:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
                    var request = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucket,
                        Key = key
                    };

                    using (var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                    using (var responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                    {
                        streamResponse.ContentLength = response.ContentLength;
                        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(streamResponse.Stream);
                        streamResponse.Stream.Position = 0;
                        return streamResponse;
                    }
}
```

Once this wrapper object (streamResponse) gets back to the controller, I return a new HttpResponse with the Content set to a new StreamContent, receiving the MemoryStream from the previous method:

```
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StreamContent(_objectFromStorageResponse.StreamResponse.Stream)
                };

                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = _objectFromStorageResponse.FileNm
                };

                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _objectFromStorageResponse.StreamResponse.ContentLength;

return httpResponseMessage;
```

Now this actually works great as far as the UI -> Api downloading is concerned. The file streams to the browser just fine.

**However, with large files (>250MB), the copying stream part gets very slow.**  So the UI has to hang for a bit, creating a poor user experience as they are waiting for their download to even begin.  Obviously I could alleviate the UI issue with displaying a message or a spinner letting the user know we are processing the download.  But I can't help but think there's a better way to get the download process started sooner for the end user.  I've tried returning the stream directly instead of copying the stream over to my own stream, but I think the controller does that itself anyway because the experience appears to be the same.

Is this the only way for me to leverage streaming S3 objects from my web api?  Is there another pattern for doing so?  Or is this just how it works and I need to show some feedback to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a combination of [Presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) and respond with HTTP 303/307 status.

Say for example you need to share object x to client.

- Generate a Presigned URL to the blob/object in S3 bucket for 2 minutes (assuming thats how long it takes to download the content).
- respond with a HTTP 303 (or 307) status and the Presigned URL.
- The browser/client app/or curl command will follow HTTP 307 redirect to S3 bucket directly using the Presigned URL.

Even if some malicious player gets hold of the Presigned URL, it is only valid for 2 minutes.

This way, your server side code doesn't have to play the middle man in transmitting the bytes. This method frees up a lot of memory and time on your server to serve other API requests.